# What am I doing wrong with the While Loop here?

Tags: python

I am getting an error that says "IndexError: List index out of range"
with the While Loop that I am using. Pls help.

```
from array import *

limit = 20
limitn = limit+1
p = 2
nums = range(p,limitn)
primes = []

while p < limitn+1: 
    for i in nums:
        if i == p:
           primes.append(i)
        if i%p == 0:
           nums.remove(i)
    p = nums[0]


print primes
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Atleast explain what the question is supposed to do, what is the input, what is the expected output etc.

Comment: Extremely sorry about that, am actually new to coding. I am trying to implement the sieve of Eratosthenes for sieving out the primes here. I am getting the error with the "While Loop" that I am using.while p < limitn+1: 
    for i in nums:
        if i == p:
           primes.append(i)
        if i%p == 0:
           nums.remove(i)
    p = nums[0]

Answer (score 1):

Your list goes out of index because at the last iteration the length of `nums` is 0 i.e the list is empty and you are referencing the first element.
Because you are in a for loop `nums.remove(index)` removes the index but does not update the list.
So `nums` still refers to the previous `nums` and it's length has been changed.
So instead of `.remove()` use slice:

```
nums = nums[: nums.index(i)] + nums[nums.index(i) + 1 :]
```

slice operator creates a new `nums` removing the element `i`.

 Your program for finding primes is not a good approach

```
for i in range(p, limitn):
     for j in range(2, i):
          if i % j == 0:
                break
     else:
          primes.append(i)
```

The code above will give you primes in your range.
 If there is anything that can be improved please comment

Answer (score 0):

With `nums.remove(i)`, `nums` will be `[]`.
So, `IndexError: List index out of range` is no problem

```
from array import *

limit = 20
limitn = limit+1
p = 2
nums = range(p,limitn)

primes = []

while p < limitn+1: 
    for i in nums:
        if i == p:
           primes.append(i)
        if i%p == 0:
           print(i)
           nums.remove(i)

    # Check nums array size
    if len(nums) == 0:
        break
    p = nums[0]


print primes
```